# Writing a count function for members in a SSRS Report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssis, count

Hello I need help writing a correct expression in SSRS report that will allow me to state "Total Attendance:*xx*" (Attendance and a Count) for the number of members for that report. I thought of using count(expression, scope, recursive) can anyone help?

Comment: Please, edit the question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: A sample of the data in your dataset and your expected results based on the sample data will get you a quicker answer. This is a bit too vague.